# Floor of very large floats in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, floor

As Python has no limit over integers but has some limit over its floats.
How do I go about calculating floor of very large floats?

I am trying to calculate floor(A*B), where A is a small irrational number, possibly sqrt(2), e, sqrt(5) etc and B is a very large number in range 10^1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html) module:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> from math import floor, sqrt
>>> 
>>> d1 = Decimal(sqrt(2))
>>> d2 = Decimal(10**1000)
>>> 
>>> result = d1 * d2
>>> floor(result)
```

---

You can also set the precision for the decimal using `getcontext().prec` in order to get more precise result.

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 100
>>> d1 = Decimal(2).sqrt()
>>> d1
Decimal('1.414213562373095048801688724209698078569671875376948073176679737990732478462107038850387534327641573')
```

Comment: Why have you done `Decimal(str(<float>))` rather than `Decimal(<float>)`

Comment: If the challenge is to calculate the accurate value of `floor(A*B)`, then this answer doesn't solve it, as precision is lost during the `sqrt(2)` step and is not restored afterwards.

Comment: Thanks @Leon and @ Andrew Gelnar for your comments, updated code.

Comment: Decimal(1.1)*Decimal(123456789123456789123456789) this is not giving right answer

Comment: Decimal(1/7) = 0.142857142857142849212692681248881854116916656494140625, but it should be 0.142857 repeating. Adjusting getcontext().prec didn't fix this.

Answer (score 0):

64 bit floats don't go above ~10^308. So your 10^1000 is definitely not going to fit, regardless of multiplication by any constant. (No 64-bit float can be small enough to make 10^1000 less than 10^308.) So your procedure isn't going to work for floats.

Consider using the `decimal` module. E.g.:

```
import decimal
import math
a = decimal.Decimal("10") ** 10000
b = decimal.Decimal("0.123")
math.floor(a*b)
```